# c# подключение к базе данных

Tags: c#

Здравствуете! У меня большое проект и я хочу подключится к базе данных один раз во время запуск программа (в program.cs) и присвою подключение к глобальное перемене, когда нужно работа с база данных я использую это подключение.

Global.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test.global
{
    class Global
    {
        public static SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection;
    }
}
```

Connection.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using test.global;

namespace test.connection
{
    class Connection
    {
        //Открываем соединение к базе данных
        public static void open()
        {
            try
            {
                //Соединяем к базе данных
                Global.sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="+Environment.CurrentDirectory+ "\\cities.db;Version=3");
                Global.sqliteConnection.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        //Закрываем соединение к базе данных
        public static void close()
        {
            if (Global.sqliteConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Global.sqliteConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Считаю это правильное подход. Но большинство людей... считают это не правильное подход!

Comment: И правильно считают. ADO.NET само держит пул подключений, вам об этом заботиться нет необходимости.

Comment: А в чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос, это подход насколько правильно или не правильно

Comment: Обычно лучше пул, но sqlite встраиваемая база данных. И если у вас нет потоков, то открытие на старте и закрытие на выходе нормально. Но если у вас есть многопоточный доступ, то могут быть проблемы.

Comment: 1) Зачем держать соединение открытым если вы не делаете запросы ? постоянно 2) база может закрывать сама соединения если долгое время не приходят запросы

Comment: Потому что мое программа для касса офисмаркета