# C#. Работа с базой данных

Tags: c#, база-данных

у меня есть приложение, работающее с MySQL, оно работает корректно, но в какой-то момент соединение с БД теряется. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему это происходит? Я попробовал решить проблему так, но это, на мой взгляд, очень неудобно:

```
    private void Operator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Global.MysqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            //Соединяем к базе данных
            MysqlConnection.Open();
        }

        if (Global.MysqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            //Получаем все поставщики из база данных
            try
            {
                MysqlCommand.Connection = Global.MysqlConnection;
                MysqlCommand.CommandText = "select provider_name, provider_id from provider";
                MysqlReader = MysqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (MysqlReader.HasRows)
                {
                    //Очищаем лист
                    comboBoxSelectProvider.Items.Clear();

                    while (MysqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        comboBoxSelectProvider.Items.Add(MysqlReader["provider_name"].ToString());
                    }
                    comboBoxSelectProvider.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    MysqlReader.Close();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Невозможно соединится с базе данных! Повторите действия еще разок ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Мой программа работает с база данных по этому я сделал одно глобальное соединение (Соединение во время запуск программа )

Comment: И там риск по соединение

Comment: И я решил что надо в каждом обращение к базе надо проверит если нет соединение то надо соединит заново, и это очень не удобно

Comment: Помогите мне как написать красивый код

Comment: Выкиньте вот это `Global.MysqlConnection` из кода, [как вам уже советовали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081785/c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85#comment1859787_1081785), и создавайте подключение каждый раз, когда оно вам нужно

Comment: Мой программа работает в кассе магазине, для каждое товар создать новый подключение получает много время!

Comment: Поэтому я создал одной глобальной соединение

Answer (score 3):

1. у базы данных есть так называемый TimeOut по истечению которого база закрывает соединение с клиентом
2. Вам уже сказали как правильно:

> Выкиньте вот это Global.MysqlConnection из кода, как вам уже советовали, и создавайте подключение каждый раз, когда оно вам нужно – tym32167 12 часов назад